# Python Threaded Server Only Serving Once

Tags: python, sockets, webserver

Trying to create a threaded http server. When I connect to this server through the webbrowser though I can only pull up one single thing before the server stops. Is there any particular reason this would be happening?

```
import socket
from threading import Thread
class http():
    def __call__():
        return 0
    def site(self):
        try:
            s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            s.bind(("localhost", 5124))
            s.listen(2)
        except socket.error, (value,message):
            if s:
                s.close()
                return 2
        c, addr = s.accept()
        s = c.recv(1024)
        print s
        c.send("test")
        c.close()
        return s

serve = http()

def happy():
    while True:
        serve.site()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Thread(target = happy()).start()
```

Answer (score 1):

try target=happy, without parentheses.

Comment: Same thing I'm getting an errno 9 bad file descriptor

Comment: This shouldn't affect the program's behavior, assuming that the OP included all the code in the program. When `happy()` is used in the `Thread` constructor, `happy` is executed but never returns, so the `Thread` object is never constructed. But all this means is that the server code runs in the original thread of execution, not in a new thread -- that won't change the program's behavior since nothing happens after creating the thread.

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes when the connection is closed and you try to reconnect before the socket leave the `TIME_WAIT` state. Try using the `socket.SO_REUSEADDR` socket option or use a random port every time.

```
import socket


s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(("localhost", 1234))
s.listen(2)
print 'listening on port %s' % s.getsockname()[1]
while True:
    c, addr = s.accept()
    buf = c.recv(1024)
    c.send(buf)
    c.close()
```

Comment: is there a better way to accomplish this besides changing the port every time?

Comment: Yes, as I said in my first answer. Look again the answer for a better example